# Threading giving NullPointerException for no reason

Tags: java, multithreading, nullpointerexception

So I'm doing this awkward example to understand how threading in Java works.
It's quite simple actually, however, I can't seem to get why this gives me a NullPointerException exception when it tries to fire more than 3 threads.

Can you sort it out? Eclipse's debugger doesn't help :-(

Thanks in advance!!

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Main boot = new Main();
    }

    public Main()
    {
        CoolThread myThread = new CoolThread(1, 2);
        Thread t_myThread = new Thread(myThread);
        t_myThread.start();

        myThread.defineMain(this);
    }


    public void teste(String tests){
        CoolThread myThread = new CoolThread(1, 2);
        Thread t_myThread = new Thread(myThread);
        t_myThread.start();
    }

}
```

---

```
public class CoolThread extends Thread {

int firstNum;
int secondNum;
Main myMain;

/**
 * Constructor
 * @param firstNum
 * @param secondNum
 */
public CoolThread(int firstNum, int secondNum)
{
    this.firstNum = firstNum;
    this.secondNum = secondNum;
}

public void defineMain(Main myMain)
{
    this.myMain = myMain;
}
/**
 * Fires the thread.
 */
public void run()
{
    try{
        int number = 0;
        for(;;)
        {

            int soma = (firstNum+secondNum);
            System.out.println("ID: " +Thread.currentThread().getId());
            firstNum++;
            secondNum++;
            number++;
            Thread.sleep(100);
            if((number % 10) == 0)
            {
                myMain.teste("The sum is: " + soma);
            }
        }
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}

}
```

By the way, this is the output I get:

```
ID: 9
ID: 9
ID: 9
ID: 9
ID: 9
ID: 9
ID: 9
ID: 9
ID: 9
ID: 9
ID: 9
ID: 12
ID: 9
ID: 12
ID: 12
ID: 9
ID: 12
ID: 9
ID: 12
ID: 9
ID: 12
ID: 9
ID: 12
ID: 9
ID: 12
ID: 9
ID: 12
ID: 9
ID: 9
ID: 12
ID: 9
ID: 14
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at my.own.package.CoolThread.run(CoolThread.java:44)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

And it goes on creating and killing threads...

Comment: And what is line 44?  I assure you something is `null` on that line.  JDK's rarely do anything for "no reason".  :-)

Comment: You have a race condition. You're starting the thread before you set mymain.

Comment: I'd also suggest reading the Oracle tutorial for threads. You're extending `Thread` then passing an instance of that to a new `Thread` object. You already have a `Thread`; your object.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are either calling `myThread.defineMain(...)` *after* starting your thread (in `Main`) or not calling `defineMain(...)` at all (in `teste(...)`).  You need to define main before the thread is running otherwise there is a chance that `myMain` is `null` when you get to line 44 which I assume is:

```
myMain.teste("The sum is: " + soma);
```

This is the definition of a [thread race condition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Race_condition).  Your start code should be:

```
CoolThread myThread = new CoolThread(1, 2);
// this must be done _before_ the thread starts below
myThread.defineMain(this);
Thread t_myThread = new Thread(myThread);
t_myThread.start();
```

*Never* think that the JDK is wrong.  That will just kill any debugging and critical thinking that you are using to find your problem.  Learn how to [use the debugger in eclipse](http://www.vogella.com/articles/EclipseDebugging/article.html).  You can then put a break-point on line 44 and investigate the variables.

Unfortunately in this case you have a threaded program and the debugging is changing the timing of the program and most likely hiding the bug.  You might have tried to print out the various objects on line 44 to see which one was `null`.

---

Also, as @kurtzbot pointed out, if `CoolThread` extends `Thread` then you can just say `new CoolThread()` and then `coolThread.start()`.  Really what you should be doing is having `CoolThread` implement `Runnable` instead of extending `Thread`.  That's the better pattern:

```
CoolThread myThread = new CoolThread(1, 2);
// this must be done _before_ the thread starts below
myThread.defineMain(this);
Thread t_myThread = new Thread(myThread);
t_myThread.start();
...

public class CoolThread implements Runnable {
    public void run() {
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: It may be worth mentioning that he does not need to put his `CoolThread` class inside of `Thread` since `CoolThread` is already extending `Thread`.  He could just do `myThread.start()`.

Comment: Oh my god... You are ABSOLUTELY right... You may slap me in the face! I deserve it...

Comment: @Gray, +1 for suggesting to implement `Runnable` instead of extending `Thread`.

Comment: @user885878, if this answer is correct and solved your problem you should accept it.  This helps other users who may stumble upon your question and see that this answer is what they should look at.

Comment: Well that's +1 for everyone here that helped. I'm just a junior programmer and it's great to have help from people like you all to point out the noob mistakes here and there! :)

Comment: @kurtzbot I was just waiting 6 minutes to accept it. I was going to choose Gray 's solution :)

Comment: Whilst I agree with this answer, it is more likely the NPE is created by the thread which is started in the teste method as defineMain is never called for this new thread.

Comment: Good point @James.  I don't see a call to `teste` but that should be pointed out.  Thanks.

Comment: @Gray The call to teste method is within the run method of CoolThread.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect myMain is null when a new thread is started from the teste method. You need to call defineMain from within the teste method like you do in the constructor for Main class.

Comment: Yeah... myMain is null. That's what happens when you're taking too much coffee 8| Thanks:)